# aws-shell is configured but it still says i need an AWS account to use mturk

Tags: amazon-web-services, mturk, aws-shell

I'm trying to use the mturk api through aws-shell.
Although I have AWS account configured, I still got this error:

[image]

When i follow the link, it leads me to this page:

[image]

"Get your access keys" leads me to the same page where I got my access keys for the configuration.

What did I do wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is your AWS IAM user have permission to MTurk? I think it is permission issue.

Follow **STEP 4** of this page to give permission to Mturk to your AWS IAM user -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkGettingStartedGuide/SetUp.html#create-iam-user-or-role